# Are there any other options available to debug this deletion issue in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I posted this issue on [the lightswitch forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/699bd660-9b8f-4627-89d1-9dfa23bf2d6d) and got nothing.  I thought I'd try one more time before giving up on Lightswitch.

I'm implementing deletes against a Sql Server database with well defined relational constraints.  For various reasons, I can't specify cascade delete on those relationships.

My approach seems correct because I am successfully deleting one entity type.  In the entity's Deleting event, I'm deleting all related children like this:

```
entity.simpleChild.Delete();

foreach (var child in entity.complexChild)
{
    ((IEntityObject)child).Delete();
}

foreach (var child in entity.ChildWithGrandChildren)
{
    foreach (var grandChild in child.Children)
    {
        ((IEntityObject)grandChild).Delete();
    }
    child.Delete();
}
```

One of my entity types is failing, however.  This entity has grandchildren, but I'm deleting those as well.  Not only that, but when I comment out the deletion of grandchildren and attempt to delete an entity that has no related grandchildren, I get the same error.  I'm deleting everything in the same order as a TSQL script that works.  At run time, however, I get this error:

*The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.*

When I profile the database, I can see lots of selects, but no attempts at deletion, so Lightswitch just *thinks* there will be a problem.  What can I do to try to figure out where the problem is?  Removing various related entities from the model never produces any different message.

Comment: Could you please post the code that is triggering this error? Be sure to indicate what context you're operating in - responding to a command, inside of a data event, etc.

Comment: Simple code sample added.  As I mentioned, this code runs in the entity's Deleting event.

Comment: If we are defining "grandchildren" as an entity that is related to the "grandparent" through an intermediate child entity, then the code you've posted is not deleting grandchildren.

Comment: Added snippet of deleting grandchildren.  I was thinking it was not necessary due to the fact that I'm attempting a particular entity that happens not to have any grandchildren, so I commented out the grandchild deletion code, and got the same error.  Not sure the deletion code could be any more basic.

Comment: Looks like you've got a complex schema; I see 2 possibilities: 1) you're missing a relationship - you aren't in fact deleting all children and grandchildren. Since it's not possible to have exactly the same syntax for a SQL script and an entity query, you've missed something when you're comparing the script that works against the entity query that doesn't. 2) Because of the complexity of your schema, you've uncovered a bug in LightSwitch entities. In either case, a full schema review would be called for, not something I want to do here. In any case, yes there is weakness in LS debugging here.

Comment: It would seem to be the latter (bug) because the same error occurs when I remove from my model most related entities (especially the grandchildren), comment out the code to delete those entities, and try again.  In that case, lightswitch doesn't even know about the entities with grandchildren, and again, no actual deletions are attempted.  It seems to incorrectly think some deletion has been neglected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that is able to successfully delete a 3 part relationship: Person - Child - Grandchild in a VS LightSwitch application. The SQL server table definitions are using DELETE NO ACTION just like your example.

```
    partial void People_Deleting(Person entity)
    {
        foreach (var child in entity.Children)
        {
            foreach (var grandchild in child.GrandChildQuery)
            {
                ((IEntityObject)grandchild).Delete();
            }

            child.Delete();
        }
    }
```

I'm struck by the fact that this code has a different structure than the sample code you've posted. In particular, this code has an inner loop that deletes grandchildren from intermediate child entities. Since you don't have an inner loop, you must either have a different strategy for deleting grandchildren which isn't shown in your sample, or that is the problem.

Comment: Dang, I changed my grandchild selection from child.GrandChildren to child.GrandChildQuery but that didn't work.  Apparently the grandchild collection and the query are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discouvered that another developer placed code in the deleting and deleted events for the child and this code caused the error.

Hope this help others facing the same problem.